# How to compress multiple files into 3 files per archive with windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, compression, 7zip

I have 100 files that look like this:

```
001.txt
002.txt
003.txt
004.txt
.....
100.txt
```

I want to compress them like this:

```
001.txt
002.txt ----> archive01.7z
003.txt
---------
004.txt
005.txt ----> archive02.7z
006.txt
```

How can I achieve this with windows batch file?Thanks in advance:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
rem initialize all variables
set counter=1
set groupnumber=1
rem change groupcount value if you want a different number of files per zip
set groupcount=3
set zipfilenamePrefix=archive
rem start looping over...
for %%f in (*) do (
    if not "%%f"=="%~nx0" (
        set fileList=!fileList! %%f
        set /a reminder=!counter!%%!groupcount!
        if !reminder! equ 0 (
            set zipfilename=archive!groupnumber!.tz
            echo Zipping files: !fileList! into !zipfilename!
            rem your zipping utility goes here: input = !fileList! and output = !zipfilename!
            set /a groupnumber=!groupnumber!+1
            set fileList=
        )
        set /a counter=counter+1
    )
)
rem there could be some left over files - last group may be less than 3 files
if !reminder! equ 0 (
    set zipfilename=archive!groupnumber!.tz
    echo Zipping into files: !fileList! !zipfilename!
    rem your zipping utility goes here: input = !fileList! and output = !zipfilename!
)
```

Comment: If there are 9 files, this script works perfectly. However, if there are 8 files, the third archive will include the batch file itself and there will be a fouth archive that contains all the files and the previous 3 archives.If there are 10 files, the last file will be ignored. I used `7za a output\!zipfilename! !filelist!` to compress the files. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: You are correct for your 8 files test case. It is taking the batch file as well because the for loop is looking for ALL files. I have modified the script above to filter the batch file from getting included in the list of files for zipping while looping. For 10 files situation, I guess you probably forgot to do the zip in the LAST if condition block (the line "rem your..." in the final if block).